# how to set mouseover using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know the basic but need more detail. I want to do same like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxpKT.jpg). 
About image: 
when we *mouseover* the box a new list occurs and when we *mouseout* that box the list still show. but when we move cursor to any other point then it hide. Please help!! 

**jquery**

```
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".nav1").mouseover(function() {
        $("#religions").show(400);
      });
    $(".nav1").mouseout(function() {
        $("#religions").hide(400);
      });
    });
  </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
</head>
```

**Html**

```
<hbox style="text-align: center; font-size: 95%; font-weight:600;">
    <div class="nav1" title="Major Religions around the World">Major Religions &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="font-size:15px;"></i></div>
</hbox>
<div id="religions" style="display: none;">
    <div class="rel_main">
      <ul>
        <li><font size="5.4">Major</font></li>
        <br>
        <li><a href="#"><font color="black">Christanarty</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font color="black">Islam</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font color="black">Hinduism</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font color="black">Chinese Folk Religion</font></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Css**

```
ul {
        list-style-type: none;
      }

.nav1 {
    display: block;
    background-color: #00AEFF;
    color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 1px 10px #888;
    line-height: 1.6;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease 0s !important;
    width: 140px;
    font-family: arial;
}
#religions {
        background-color: #F1F1F1;
        color: black;
        height: 350px;
        width: 1129px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
      }
 .rel_main {
        background-color: #F1F1F1;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        height: 300px;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin-left: -25px;
        color: black;
      }
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: You can use **very** basic CSS to achieve this exact same thing. Does it have to be with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add like

```
$( "#outer" ).mouseover(function() {
 //your action
});
```

check jquery API document https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$( "#outer" ).mouseover(function() {
  //Code here
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

And when mouse leaving element you can add:

```
$( "#outer" ).mouseleave(function() {
  //Code here
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".nav1").hover(

        function () {
            $('#religions').slideDown('medium');
        },

        function () {
            $('#religions').slideUp('medium');
        }
    );

});
```

**Check out fiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/ggChris/evf6bgn7/

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you put javascript code

replace it with

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav1").mouseover(function() {
    $("#religions").show();
  });
$("#religions").mouseover(function() {
    $("#religions").show();
  });
      $("#religions").mouseout(function() {
    $("#religions").hide();
  });
});
```

see your response [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOmPbG)

Happy Coding